# Is there a one-liner for this string manipulation I'm attempting?

Tags: c#, string

I have a string of the following format:
"[someTitle1]firstName$$[someTitle2]secondName$$[someTitle3]thirdName$$[someTitle4]fourthName$$[someTitle5]fifthName$$[someTitle6]sixthName"

and I want to receive from it the following string:
`"thirdName.fourthName.fifthName.sixthName"` (length of the input string may vary, but I want to always get the last four elements (it is guaranteed to have at least 4)).

Can I do this in one line (or close to it)?

Comment: Split by `$$` then split by `]`?

Comment: @GSerg Splitting by `$$` is obvious, my main problem is to get rid of the titles and their brackets

Comment: You don't have to. Splitting by `]` you get the clean name in the second element and garbage in the first.

Answer (score 3):

With the new C# [Indices and ranges](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/tutorials/ranges-indexes) (C# 8.0, .NET Core only) this becomes a one liner:

```
string result = String.Join('.', Regex.Split(input, @"(^|\$\$)\[\w+]")[^4..]);
```

Note that this Regex uses the `$$[someTitle]` parts as separators (or just `[someTitle]` at the beginning).

`(^|\$\$)` matches the beginning of the line (`^`) or (`|`) the double `$` escaped with `\`, because `$` has the special meaning "end of line" in regex otherwise. `[` is escaped as well because it denotes the beginning of a character set otherwise. `\w` denotes an alphanumeric character. `+` means that there is at least one of them but possibly many. If other characters than letters and digits may appear in the titles, then replace `\w+` by `.+?` (resulting in **`(^|\$\$)\[.+?]`** ) where `.` stands for any character. `+?` means at least one but as few as possible, otherwise `.+` would consume the ending `]` up to the very last `]`.

With .NET Standard 2.1 / .NET Core 2.0 you can use the new `TakeLast` LINQ extension method:

```
string result = String.Join(".", Regex.Split(input, @"(^|\$\$)\[\w+]").TakeLast(4));
```

With other versions of C#:

```
string result =
    String.Join(".", Regex.Split(input, @"(^|\$\$)\[\w+]").Reverse().Take(4).Reverse());
```

Comment: You don't need the `ToArray` calls as there's an overload of `string.Join` that takes `IEnumerable<string>`

Comment: Yes, but only since .NET 5.0

Comment: What gives you that idea? String.Join has accepted an IEnumerable for... Like ever

Comment: @pinkfloydx33, @juharr: It seems you are both right. It exists since .NET 4.0 with a `string` as separator and since .NET Core 2.0/.NET Standard 2.1 with a `char` as separator. I had to expand the "Applies to" section to see it.

Answer (score 1):

Regex to capture all words preceded with ']'.  Then extract the 'Value' from each match.  Reverse the order, get the first four, then reverse again.  Then join it by '.'.

```
var last4 = 
    new Regex(@"(?<=\])\w+")
    .Matches(str)
    .Cast<Match>()
    .Select(match => match.Value)
    .Reverse()
    .Take(4)
    .Reverse()
    .Aggregate((a,b) => a + '.' + b);
```

Comment: The regex should really search for the double question marks as the end of a match as the names might contain non-word characters, and maybe even single question marks.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you always have at least 4 of the title/name pairs you can do the split on the `$$` first and then use skip to get the last four pairs and split on `]` to get just the name part.  Just be aware that you might want to add checks to make sure `pairs` has a length of at least 4 and that when you do the split on `]` that it actually results in 2 results if it's possible to have input that doesn't match your format.  This also assumes you don't have double question marks or square brackets in the titles or names.

```
var pairs = str.Split(new[] { "$$" });
var lastFour = pairs.Skip(pairs.Length -4)
    .Select(x => x.Split(']')[1]);
var result = string.Join(".", lastFour);
```

Answer (score 0):

Too many folks jump to using a `Regex` to solve every problem.  However, parsing something like that is exactly what Regexes are good at.

First create a pattern:

```
private const string NameTitlePattern = @"\[(?<title>\w+)](?<name>\w+)[(\$\$)$]";
private static readonly Regex _nameTitleRegex = new Regex(NameTitlePattern);
```

That pattern uses *named groups*, the first one is named `"title"` and consists of all *word characters* between square brackets (if your rule is different, it would be easy to change).

The second is named `"name"` and follows the closing square bracket, using the same "one or more *word characters*" rule, continuing either until two dollar signs (`\$\$`) or the end of the line (`$`) is reached.

At this point, all you need is a little code:

```
private const string NameTitleStuff =
    @"[someTitle1]firstName$$[someTitle2]secondName$$[someTitle3]thirdName$$[someTitle4]fourthName$$[someTitle5]fifthName$$[someTitle6]sixthName";
```

and

```
var result = new List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>();
var matches = _nameTitleRegex.Matches(NameTitleStuff);
foreach (var match in matches.Cast<Match>())
{
    var groups = match.Groups;
    result.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>(groups["title"].ToString(), groups["name"].ToString()));
}
```

When this runs, the variable `result` will contain a list of *name-value pairs* that are all the names and titles in the string.  You can do what you want with them at this point.  No, it's not "one line of code", but it is readable and maintainable.

If you don't value readability as much as I do, you can coalesce the `foreach` loop into a single line of LINQ:

```
var result = matches
    .Cast<Match>()
    .Select(match => match.Groups)
    .Select(groups => new KeyValuePair<string, string>(
        groups["title"].ToString(),
        groups["name"].ToString()))
    .ToList();
```